# Включение файлов С++

Tags: c, include, c++

Как исключить круговое включение файлов в C++ и C при использовании директивы #include?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существует два стандартных способа решения этой проблемы. Первый, непортируемый, - использование директивы `#pragma once` в начале `.h` файла. Второй - использование деректив `#ifndef #define #endif`. Например, если мы имеем .h файл с именем `SomeClass.h`, то его следует оформить следующим образом:

```
#ifndef _SOME_CLASS_H_
#define _SOME_CLASS_H_

// all SomeClass.h content

#endif /* _SOME_CLASS_H_ */
```